# Can't run VS 2013 projects even though the redistributable is already installed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, msvcr120.dll

I'm trying to use VS 2015 to build and run a project that was originally created in VS 2013. When I do, it gives me an error message saying I can't run it because MSVCR120D.dll is missing from my computer. I tried to install the VS 2013 redistributables from the microsoft website, but that didn't help. Looking in my System32 folder revealed that even after installing it, all I have is MSVCR120.dll, not MSVCR120D.dll. I also tried downloading the .dll file on its own from opendll.com and placing it in the correct folder, but that did not solve the issue. What do I do here? I have no idea how I'm supposed to install this .dll I need.

Comment: MSVCR120D.dll  is the __debug__ dll and is not/can not be included in the redist' package.  You need to build a release version.

Comment: So it is not possible to install that .dll without installing vs 2013 itself?

Comment: The debug versions are only delivered with the compiler, and not distributed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set platform toolset to v140 in project properties?

[image: Project properties image]